# Read text from file line by line instead of agrs and return results in Java Scanner

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out a way to do this:

```
./program input-to-scan.txt > try the word list line by line > print result
```

instead of:

```
./program word1 word2 word3 etc..
```

the working args code was :

```
// Print out command line arguments
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(initializeKeyPair(args[i]).toString());
}
```

The not working read from file code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Print out command line arguments
    File file = new File("input.txt");

    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            int i = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(initializeKeyPair(line[i]).toString());
        }
        sc.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The `initializeKeyPair` method:

```
public static BigInteger initializeKeyPair(String word) throws Exception {
    byte[] publicKeyHash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(Crypto.getPublicKey(word));
    BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(1,
        new byte[] {publicKeyHash[7], publicKeyHash[6], publicKeyHash[5],
            publicKeyHash[4], publicKeyHash[3], publicKeyHash[2],
            publicKeyHash[1], publicKeyHash[0]});
    return bigInteger;
}
```

Compiling Error:

```
program.java:1018: error: cannot find symbol
            System.out.println(initializeKeyPair(line[i]).toString());
                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable line
  location: class program
1 error
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**

Working code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
// Print out command line arguments
    for ( int i=0; i < args.length; i++ ) 
    {
        String filename = args[i];
        System.out.println("Scanning file " + filename + " ...");
        File file = new File( filename );
        try 
        { 
            Scanner filescanner = new Scanner( file );
            while ( filescanner.hasNext() ) {
                String line = filescanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println(initializeKeyPair(line).toString() + ":" + line );
            }
            filescanner.close();
        } 
        catch ( FileNotFoundException fnf ) 
        {
            System.out.println("    OOPS! " + filename + " was not found.");
        }
```

Comment: The error and your source don't match, there is no `line[]` in your source declared or used

Comment: code says args[i] and error says like[i]. can you paste actual code with proper error and what;s that initializeKeyPair method?

Comment: yes i tried both line[i] and args[i] they give the same Error.

Comment: `public static BigInteger initializeKeyPair(String word) throws Exception {
 
 byte[] publicKeyHash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(Crypto.getPublicKey(word));
 BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(1, new byte[] {publicKeyHash[7], publicKeyHash[6], publicKeyHash[5], publicKeyHash[4], publicKeyHash[3], publicKeyHash[2], publicKeyHash[1], publicKeyHash[0]});
 
 return bigInteger;
 
    }`

Comment: @xhxx you've edited your code and changes `line` to `args`, but since the exception mentions the variable `line` explicitly, I've changed it back. And please don't  post code as a comment. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Thanks all I've successfully managed to get it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `line[i]` with `Value.indexOf(i)`.

`cannot find symbol` means that the variable `line[i]` was not found. Indeed, you never declared or even assigned anything in it, but you try to read from it.

And as your `initializeKeyPair()` takes a `String` as an argument, you'll want to cast your integer to a `String`, using `String.valueOf()`